# IOS - Pass local storage between WebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, webview, local-storage

I'm working with an IOS mobile application. 
The thing is I have two different webview and what I want is to pass localStorage data from one webview to the other. Is it possible? How should I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the iOS5 SDK, `UIWebView` has default cache enabled, so all you need is include cache in your HTML. try it out.